# Alert view shifted upwards due to the addition of Text field in it

Tags: ios

I am creating an Alert view on click of a button. I have placed a UITextfield in it. But the Alertview is shifted upwards in the screen. I am not able to bring it back at the center of the screen.

Here is my code and Screenshot.
[image]

and the code for creating this Alert view is this:-

```
- (IBAction)btn_cancelAppointment_click:(id)sender
{
    // Here We are Creating Alertview which asks for
    UIAlertView* cancelAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];

    [cancelAlert setDelegate:self];
    [cancelAlert setTitle:@"Are you sure you want to request cancellation of this appointment?"];
    [cancelAlert setMessage:@"                             "];
    [cancelAlert addButtonWithTitle:@"NO"];
    [cancelAlert addButtonWithTitle:@"YES"];

    UITextField * txt_cancelNote = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 88.0, 245.0, 30.0)];

    [txt_cancelNote setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [txt_cancelNote setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    [txt_cancelNote setPlaceholder:@"Enter cancellation note"];
    txt_cancelNote.tag = 11;

    [cancelAlert addSubview:txt_cancelNote];
    cancelAlert.delegate = self;
    [cancelAlert show];
}
```

So, if somebody can tell me how to bring it back to the center of the screen. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try by setting the **transform** property of the `UIAlertView`

```
  UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Test" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
  alertView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(x, y);
```